# jQuery closest();

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, closest

I'm trying to animate an image which is partly hidden (via overflow: hidden) inside a list item. I want this to happen when a user hovers over an A tag inside the same list item.

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="projects" class="section">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/img/projects/pf6.jpg" width="980" height="500" alt="Project title" />
            <h2 class="left middle"><span>new</span><a href="#">Title 1</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/img/projects/pf4.jpg" width="980" height="500" alt="Project title" />
            <h2 class="bottom right"><a href="#">Title 2</a></h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My basic css:

```
#projects ul li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#projects ul li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
}
```

I am trying the following with jQuery to move the image (to no avail):

```
$("#projects li h2 a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).closest("img").animate({paddingTop: "50px"}, "slow");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).closest("img").animate({paddingTop: "0"}, "slow");
    }
);
```

Anyone have any idea why this is not working! - any help much appreciated :-)

Comment: I recently discovered that animations that involve overflow can get dicey in FireFox.  In my case, it was a div with overflow, and I actually moved it's containing element, but it made a mess in FireFox.  I'm not (at all) sure that this is going to apply to you, but I do suggest you do some testing in FireFox and other browsers.

Comment: I recommend using native `closest` like this `$(this.closest('img')).animate...` it will increase code significantly (see http://jsperf.com/jquery-closest-vs-element-closest)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`closest()` only selects the current element and its parent elements (and then limits it to the first match).

Your `img` element isn't a parent of the link you have the hover handler on, therefore it doesn't work.

**Update:** as ScottyUSCD pointed out, the previous code I posted won't work.   I misread the source and thought the elements were siblings.

His answer was correct:

```
$(this).closest("li").children("img")
```

This will navigate up to the closest parent `li` element, then look through that element's children for any `img` elements.

Comment: Oh nifty, I didn't know that one.  I would have used parent().find()

Comment: Great - thanks...

So my javascript should be:

$("#projects li h2 a").hover(
  function () {
   $(this).prevAll("img").animate({paddingTop: "10px"}, "slow");
  }, 
  function () {
   $(this).prevAll("img").animate({paddingTop: "0"}, "slow");
  }
 );

Struggling to make this work still - sorry!

Comment: This isn't going to work because "a" AND "img" aren't siblings.

a is a child of  "h2"

Comment: @ScottyUCSD, yes, you are right, I misread the HTML.   The answer you posted will work.

Answer (score 11):

I think it should be:

```
$(this).closest("li").children("img").animate()
```

Or you could do:

```
$(this).closest("h2").prevAll("img")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `<img>` could also be after the `<h2>`, use:

```
$(this).closest("h2").siblings("img");
```